US smart plugs with UK Alexa?
I'm moving to the Philippines where they us US plugs. If I purchase US smart plugs will they work with my UK bought Alexa devices? Pop, echo, show

A general answer is tricky. You shouldn't consider smart plugs as US or UK plugs but as smart plugs which happen to have US or UK pins. The smart side most likely doesn't care about it. If I had to guess it will likely work. The restrictions will likely be on the organizations providing the integration on plug and Amazon side. So maybe the plug integration doesn't work in the Philippines due to SW country restrictions.

Most devices now work with the full 110-230V AC 50/60Hz range. So, the UK devices should work everywhere, as long as you get the right plug mechanical adapters. To be sure, check the small print on the back of the devices. Licensing by country maybe an issue though. Some apps may not work anymore when you move to a different country.
